# override remote address in eks service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an app I am trying to adapt to EKS.
IN my app logic , my portal takes the remote_addr field in the request it is getting , ( whether it is an ip or a dns ) and passes it to the backend component. The backend checks that field and decides based on that whether to handle the request or not.

For some reason when I put my app in EKS , that field always contains the portal pod ip.
Ofcourse that the portal and the backend gave a service between them so I am guessing the service is adding this ip or perhaps the kube-proxy.
How can I override that field and make sure that field does not contain the pod ip but some other dns I prefer?